# How to avoid postgresql from changing column names when using "select trim"

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, trim

I run the following query in my `PostgreSql version 9.3` (I'm using `PgAdmin III`):

```
Select trim(both ' ' from column1) from myTable
```

it returns the data I want, but it also renames the column name from `'column1'` to `'btrim'`. I need the original column name because I'm using this query from a Java app. This renaming happens with ALL the columns where I use the `Trim` function, no matter if I run the query directly in pgAdmin or via my [postgres jdbc driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) (this is why I think the problem is in postgres itself).

How can I get the data and the columns with their right names when using the `Trim` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use column aliases:

```
Select trim(both ' ' from column1) AS column1 
from myTable
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f4c67/2/0)**</kbd>

If you need case sensitive aliases you need to quote them with `"`.

> [**Idenfifiers**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):
>
> **Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted
> names are always folded to lower case.** For example, the identifiers
> FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo"
> and "FOO" are different from these three and each other. (The folding
> of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the
> SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper
> case. Thus, foo should be equivalent to "FOO" not "foo" according to
> the standard. If you want to write portable applications you are
> advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.)

Comment: It works in both pg Admin and my jdbc driver :D Just a little detail: postgre insists on using only lowercases when aliasing, for having uppercases the query will be: Select trim(both ' ' from column1) AS "Column1" 
from myTable